# IE XDomainRequest responseText and HTML

Tags: ajax, regex, internet-explorer-8, xdomainrequest

I'm using XDomainRequest in IE 8 to get the contents of a web page. The reponseText contains escaped characters and unicode characters that prevent the markup from being inserted into a div. This is an example of the returned data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-\/\/W3C\/\/DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional\/\/EN\" \"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/TR\/xhtml1\/DTD\/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\u000d\u000a<html xmlns=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/1999\/xhtml\">\u000d\u000a<head>\u000d\u000a    <title>...<\/title>\u000d\u000a    <script src=\"\/\/ajax.googleapis.com\/ajax\/libs\/jquery\/1.7.1\/jquery.min.js\" type=\"text\/javascript\"><\/script>\u000d\u000a<\/head>\u000d\u000a<body>\u000d\u000a\u000d\u000a<div style=\"font-size:24px;font-weight:bold\">\u000d\u000aText Headline: \u000d\u000a<\/div>\u000d\u000a\u000d\u000a<div style=\"float:left;width:50%;margin:0;padding:0;\">\u000d\u000a<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<\/p>\u000d\u000a\u000d\u000a<p>In nec imperdiet lectus.
```

When I use decodeURI or decodeURIComponent I get the "The URI to be decoded is not a valid encoding" error.

Can someone suggest a method or a regex to clean up the HTML?

Answer (score -1):

Based on my quick test:

```
regex = /\\([^u])/g;
// put it in a JSON object so that JS doesn't automatically de-escape
string = JSON.stringify({response: '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-\/\/W3C\/\/DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional\/\/EN\" \"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/TR\/xhtml1\/DTD\/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\u000d\u000a<html xmlns=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/1999\/xhtml\">\u000d\u000a<head>\u000d\u000a    <title>...<\/title>\u000d\u000a    <script src=\"\/\/ajax.googleapis.com\/ajax\/libs\/jquery\/1.7.1\/jquery.min.js\" type=\"text\/javascript\"><\/script>\u000d\u000a<\/head>\u000d\u000a<body>\u000d\u000a\u000d\u000a<div style=\"font-size:24px;font-weight:bold\">\u000d\u000aText Headline: \u000d\u000a<\/div>\u000d\u000a\u000d\u000a<div style=\"float:left;width:50%;margin:0;padding:0;\">\u000d\u000a<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<\/p>\u000d\u000a\u000d\u000a<p>In nec imperdiet lectus.'});

string.replace(regex, '$1');
```

will replace all of the escaping slashes except on the Unicode. I don't think there's many other non-escaping uses for forward slashes in JS.